# Git Bash for Windows - whoami different from $USERNAME

Tags: windows, git-bash

I have installed git for windows (including git bash), and I noticed that the output of `whoami` is different from `$USERNAME`

```
% whoami
AzureAD+KavyaJindal

% echo $USERNAME
KavyaJindal
```

In Windows command prompt:

```
% whoami
azuerad\kavyajindal
```

In `netplwiz`, it is `KavyaJindal`

Due to this, my bash prompt (`\u`) in git bash is using `AzureAD+KavyaJindal` which looks weird. How can I "set" my username in git bash to be same as my user account name in Windows?

I am not sure what to even try to make this happen.